# Boot drive not recognised at all

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, hard-drive, macos, startup

After doing an update for iPad and open Google Chrome to watch streaming movies the MacBook Pro 13 mid 2012 has started to slow down and Chrome closed.
I restarted and a flashing folder appeared instead of an Apple with a question mark.

I tried every possible key combination, it no longer detects the hard drive, in the terminal it only sees Apple_HFS Mac OS X Base System and no longer the journal hard drive + HFs.

I tried to insert the installation CD it says that there is not enough space, I tried to restore from backup but it continues to admit that there is no space, if I start the Mac with USB with OS El Capitan gives me a Panic error.

Can anyone tell me what commands to execute to restore my Mac?
I tried also to take it apart and change HD but it always goes out the folder with the question mark, Hard test does not detect any problem.

[image: !]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the HD had died, but if you tried another drive with no joy, then it may just be the SATA cable that needs replacing.

That would be my first recommendation.
Otherwise take it to a professional.